# Package dependencies in answers

Tags: discussion

It's not uncommon that answers to questions use a package which itself loads another package. In that case, details of the answer might end up being opaque if the answer uses commands documented in the dependency, but not in the actually loaded package.

Some common cases where this is the case:

- various table packages that all load `array`
- various packages that load `xcolor` and/or `graphicx`

I suggest that we try to explicitly mention and load the dependencies in answer code if the answer uses commands from both the main package and the dependency.

Here's some answers of the sort I have in mind: (I didn't really want to pick on people so I didn't add specific answers in my original version of the question.)

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39047/2693 This answer was what prompted my question in the first place. (The issue is much less obvious in the answers present state). Peter's initial answer just used the `collcell` package, but part of the answer used `\newcolumntype`. In fact, Martin (author of `collcell`) is explicit in his documentation about the use of `array`, so in this particular case, there isn't too much of a problem.  In it's current state, since there has been some discussion independently about the `array` package, so the problem doesn't really arise any more.
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23690/2693 Here the comment makes it clear that the OP didn't necessarily understand the syntax of `newcolumntype`; the `beamer` documentation won't help other than (presumably) a pointer to `array`.

Here's an answer of mine that does what I'm suggesting:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37240/2693
  The solution here uses `\resizebox` which is a `graphicx` command.  Although `beamer` loads `graphicx` it makes little sense to *just* use `beamer` in the solution, so I loaded `graphicx` explicitly with a comment in the code to that effect.

Comment: About your example answer: You actually never say that `\resizebox` comes from `graphicx` (which it actually doesn't, it comes from `graphics`; not that it really matters). You have a comment "loaded by beamer, but included here for explicitness" there, which for some new users might be more confusing than helpful. IMHO, it would be better mentioning it in the normal text before: "You could wrap the table in `\resizebox` from the `graphicx` package. This package is already loaded by `beamer`." (Also you still miss a `%` in this answer; see my comment there)

Comment: @Martin, yes, you're right. I've updated the answer.  And the point of this question is to remind people that it's a good idea to do.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not so sure. It depends on how common the packages are. I'd say that `array`, `xcolor` and `graphicx` are 'standard', in the sense that I use them directly or indirectly in every real document I write. So anything which does not work with them is basically erroneous in itself. On the other hand, if a package requires say TikZ then I think it probably is worth a mention.

Comment: I guess what I have in mind is an answer that says "Use package X" and then uses a command from e.g. `array` in the answer.  If the OP reads the documentation for package X, they won't find documentation for the command.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I can imagine such situation. Do you have an example. Do you mean something like this: "You can manipulate the command via `\preto` provided by `etoolbox`. The package `abc` loads `etoolbox` by default".

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I've added some example answers. (I didn't really want to call people out.)  But I think the answer to your question is 'yes'.  If your answer uses something from a dependency, you should make that clear in the answer so that people can look at the documentation for that package, even if some other package loads it.